# SQL Server - MS Access cannot handle decimal(19,4) type

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, decimal, numeric

I've searched everywhere for some advice on this, however have come up with nothing. We have a database running on SQL server.

We want to convert a field (used for currency) from numeric(18,2) to numeric / decimal(19,4).

I have tried to convert it multiple times, updated the table link and have the following error:

1. After the field type conversion and updating the links - **the records all work fine**.
2. If I then update a value within the numeric column to have 4 decimal places (e.g. I change 12.34 to 12.3456)
3. The record successfully updates in the database
4. After this **I cannot re-update that particular record at all - even other fields**

I cannot think of any reason why this would be the case and am hoping some SQL server expert could shed some light on it for me?

Thanks in advance!!!!
Karl

Comment: Sounds like you're leaving a transaction open, and its imposing a row lock on the rows you have updated.  How exactly are you doing the update?  Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the update is working fine before converting the field type - it is simply through changing values in a text box in a MS Access 2003 form!

Comment: In fact, even with the new format - decimal(19,4) - it still works fine if you update the price in exactly the same way as a value to 2dp. It is only after a record has a price to 3 or more DP that it stops working... ???

Comment: Try opening the Access linked table in Datasheet view and editing the currency value there. I just tried it in Access 2010 with an Access_2003-format .mdb file and it worked fine for me. (I noted that the SQL Server `DECIMAL(19,4)` column is mapped to Access' `Currency` type in the linked table.)

Comment: Still no luck with this - even if I edit the Access table directly. Another finding today - if the cell had an integer in before the conversion - it behaves fine, however if the cell had a decimal number in before the conversion - it causes the update problems!